# How to hide TODO state and Priority in org-agenda-custom-command?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I do not want TODO states ("TODO, DONE") and priorities ("[#A]") for tasks to be displayed in one of my custom agenda views. I have not been able to find any settings that would accomplish this. Is there any way this can be achieved?

Ideally, I would like to be able to toggle the visibility of TODO states and priorities separately.

Comment: I want that too. I resorted to using 2charater TODO keywords (TD, DN) and I use gray faces and a smaller font for todo keywords and priorities, so they are less obtrusive.

Comment: For hiding TODO states I `(setq org-agenda-todo-keyword-format "")`. I do not know how to hide priorities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could postprocess `org-agenda-format-item` and add your own trimming function. Here is an example that removes my(!) todo keywords and strips the priority down to just one letter:

```
(defun myTrim (s)
    ; remove todo keyword and trimp priorities to just one letter
    (replace-regexp-in-string
     "[]#[]" "" 
     (replace-regexp-in-string "\\(TD\\|NX\\|WT\\|DN\\) " "" s)))
```

Adjust this to your needs. Then you can turn the stripping off and on by adding or removing the advice:

```
(advice-add 'org-agenda-format-item  :filter-return #'myTrim)
(advice-remove 'org-agenda-format-item  #'myTrim)
```

I am pretty sure this will break *something*. I lost the fontification of the priority, but you wanted to remove the priority entirely, so this won't hurt you. Sorting by priority is probably also endangered.

Answer (score 2):

TODO states may be modified in agenda views by setting the org-agenda-todo-keyword-format variable. To hide the TODO state entirely, use the following line in a org agenda custom command:

```
          (org-agenda-todo-keyword-format "")
```

Documentation:
org-agenda-todo-keyword-format is a variable defined in ‘org-agenda.el’.
Format for the TODO keyword in agenda lines.
Set this to something like "%-12s" if you want all TODO keywords
to occupy a fixed space in the agenda display.

I have not found a way to hide priorities yet.